# Showing fields of queried [object Object] in console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using `"express": "3.2.6",`, `nodeJS v0.10.25` and `"express-myconnection": "1.0.4",`.

My database connection seems to work. However, when going to my view to query:

```
console.log("Data: " + rows);
```

I get the following output:

```
Data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

My query method looks like the following:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,rows)     {

            if(err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

            console.log("Data: " + rows);
            res.render('index.ejs',{page_title:"Customer - Node.js",data:rows});

        });

    });
};
```

My `customer table` looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `street` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `typeOfTransaction` enum('buy','sell') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Any recommendations how I can display the data as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using string concatenation (`string + object`).

Change:

```
console.log("Data: " + rows);
```

To:

```
console.log("Data:", rows);
```

--

#### Demo

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };

console.log("Data: " + obj);
console.log("Data:", obj);
```